# Angular 6 - Call function in immediate parent component, not page component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular-event-emitter

I am using angular 6 to create a tabs module. I have split it up into two components, tab bar and a tab.

```
  <tab-bar>
    <tab (tabSelected)="selectTab(1)"></tab>
    <tab (tabSelected)="selectTab(2)"></tab>
    <tab (tabSelected)="selectTab(3)"></tab>
  </tab-bar>
```

When a tab is clicked it emits tabSelected which should then trigger selectTab within the tab bar component. The issue i have is that tabSelected attempts to trigger within the page module instead of within the tab-bar module (its immediate parent).

I am hoping somebody may know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You've got to put `tab` components in `tab-bar` template.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it seems that after click it tries to call `selectTab` method on component where all provided code is located. I assume that you need to call `selectTab` which exists on `tap-bar` component. It means that you need to place your tabs inside `tapbar` component template.

Your tapbar.component.html should include this:

```
<tab (tabSelected)="selectTab(1)"></tab>
<tab (tabSelected)="selectTab(2)"></tab>
<tab (tabSelected)="selectTab(3)"></tab>
```

And in the place, where you want to have your tabs:

```
<tab-bar></tap-bar>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you want exactly the behaviour you described (not moving the tabs to tab-bar component), you can simply export your component / directive reference to the template:

tab-bar.component.ts

```
@Component({
   ...
   exportAs: 'tabBar'
})
```

Then in your template use this exported reference as a local template variable:

```
<tab-bar #tabBar="tabBar">
  <tab (tabSelected)="tabBar.selectTab(1)"></tab>
  <tab (tabSelected)="tabBar.selectTab(2)"></tab>
  <tab (tabSelected)="tabBar.selectTab(3)"></tab>
</tab-bar>
```